# Will Apple Cinema work on my laptop?

Tags: display

I have an HP with HDMI and VGA ports, and HD 3000 and HD6770M graphics.

Will the Cinema 27" work with my laptop with full capabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look promising for you, but that may be for the better.  The cinema displays are extremely over priced relative to any equally quality display from Samsung/Dell/etc.

Source: [CNET](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20043524-263.html)

[image: Does not look promising]